# Issue with a text editor in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: text-editor

Text editor does not show the latest parts of the text format files when I take up it to the left side of the screen. like below image

> [image]

Comment: Show two screenshots of how it should look like and of how it shouldn't look like. Make screenshots of full but not maximized text editor window.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Please articulate more.

Comment: two lines are not shown in the simple image sometimes this issue happened for me and I don't know what this issue depends on. it occurred on java codes and sometimes on python codes.